# How can I change the markup produced by Ninja Forms after the form has been printed on the page?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, ninja-forms

This is what I gotta deal with:

```
<nf-field>
    <div id="nf-field-2-container" class="nf-field-container lastname-container  label-above ">
        <div class="nf-before-field">
            <nf-section></nf-section>
        </div>
        <div class="nf-field">
            <div id="nf-field-2-wrap" class="field-wrap lastname-wrap nf-fail nf-error" data-field-id="2">
                <div class="nf-field-label">
                    <label for="nf-field-2" class="">Last Name <span class="ninja-forms-req-symbol">*</span> </label>
                </div>
                <div class="nf-field-element">
                    <input id="nf-field-2" name="nf-field-2" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nf-after-field">
            <nf-section>
                <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>
                <div class="nf-error-wrap nf-error">
                    <div class="nf-error-msg nf-error-required-error">This is a required field.</div>
                </div>
            </nf-section>
        </div>
    </div>
</nf-field>
```

Please notice the `<nf-field>` tag. It isn't HTML and has nothing I can use to style it with, regarding what type of input it is, ie. text, textarea, etc.

I have no previous experience of backbone.js and all the javascript by Ninja Forms is minified, so I don't know where to even begin with all that. This is what I did come up with:

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.nf-field-container').unwrap('nf-field');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This javascript is placed and the very bottom of the page, just before `</body>`. My excitement was short lived when I discovered that for some reason it only works on hard reload (at least when I develop on localhost).

Comment: Where is the view code that initialize/makes use of the ninja form thingy?

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried targeting it in CSS with just `nf-field` as a selector?

Answer (score 0):

The whole form is wrapped in a div that has the class `.nf-form-cont` (or just create it if there isn't).

Your JS should look like this:

```
(function ($) {
     $(window).load(function(){
       // Remove unnecessary NF mark ups
       $('.nf-form-cont').find("nf-field").contents().unwrap();
       $('.nf-form-cont').find("nf-fields-wrap").contents().unwrap();
       $('.nf-form-cont').find("nf-section").contents().unwrap();
       $('.nf-form-cont').find("nf-errors").contents().unwrap();
     });
})(jQuery);
```